# Pandas - filling NaNs in Categorical data

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to fill missing values (NAN) using the below code

```
NAN_SUBSTITUTION_VALUE = 1
g = g.fillna(NAN_SUBSTITUTION_VALUE)
```

but I am getting the following error

```
ValueError: fill value must be in categories.
```

Would anybody please throw some light on this error.

Answer (score 80):

Your question is missing the important point what `g` is, especially that it has dtype `categorical`. I assume it is something like this:

```
g = pd.Series(["A", "B", "C", np.nan], dtype="category")
```

The problem you are experiencing is that `fillna` requires a value that already exists as a category. For instance, `g.fillna("A")` would work, but `g.fillna("D")` fails. To fill the series with a new value you can do:

```
g_without_nan = g.cat.add_categories("D").fillna("D")
```

Comment: Works like a charm. +1 for both the question and the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 43):

Add the category before you fill:

```
g = g.cat.add_categories([1])
g.fillna(1)
```

Comment: Just a side tought: when using directly applied to a data frame I had to specify the column in order for it to work: `g[cat_column_name] = g[cat_column_name].cat.add_categories([1]) `. And the added category goes as largest if categories are already ordered.

Answer (score 6):

Once you create *Categorical Data*, you can insert only values in category.

```
>>> df
    ID  value
0    0     20
1    1     43
2    2     45

>>> df["cat"] = df["value"].astype("category")
>>> df
    ID  value    cat
0    0     20     20
1    1     43     43
2    2     45     45

>>> df.loc[1, "cat"] = np.nan
>>> df
    ID  value    cat
0    0     20     20
1    1     43    NaN
2    2     45     45

>>> df.fillna(1)
ValueError: fill value must be in categories
>>> df.fillna(43)
    ID  value    cat
0    0     20     20
1    1     43     43
2    2     45     45
```

Comment: Your way to solve the problem it is very would. Could you please add some more text, I find it tooo difficult to follow

Answer (score 2):

As many have said before, this error comes from the fact that that feature's type is 'category'.

I suggest converting it to string first, use fillna and finally convert it back to category if needed.

```
g = g.astype('string')
g = g.fillna(NAN_SUBSTITUTION_VALUE)
g = g.astype('category')
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you may want to replace the NaN with values present in your dataset, you can use that then:

```
#creates a random permuation of the categorical values
permutation = np.random.permutation(df[field])

#erase the empty values
empty_is = np.where(permutation == "")
permutation = np.delete(permutation, empty_is)

#replace all empty values of the dataframe[field]
end = len(permutation)
df[field] = df[field].apply(lambda x: permutation[np.random.randint(end)] if pd.isnull(x) else x)
```

It works quite efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

The deep understanding is because:

> Categoricals can only take on only a limited, and usually fixed, number of possible values (categories). In contrast to statistical categorical variables, a Categorical might have an order, but numerical operations (additions, divisions, …) are not possible.

> All values of the Categorical are either in categories or np.nan. Assigning values outside of categories will raise a ValueError. Order is defined by the order of the categories, not lexical order of the values.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html

Answer (score 0):

I came accross this problem when trying to fill the missing values from another categorical series. For that, setting the missing values in the target series is not enough. Both series have to share the same categories:

```
one = pd.Series(["A", "B", "C", None], dtype="category")
two = pd.Series(["A", "C", "B", "D"], dtype="category")
combined_categories = pd.concat([one.dropna(), two.dropna()]).unique()
one = one.cat.set_categories(combined_categories)
two = two.cat.set_categories(combined_categories)

result = one.fillna(two)
```